# Scraping elements with changing xpath under same class

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to scrape "li" elements that will change their xpath depending on how many "li" elements will be added. I don't know how to describe that better, so I will go right into the example to make it more clear.

Let's say this is about scraping soccer data. The structure of the website is as follows:

```
<ul class="stats">
    <p class="results">Man of The Match</p>
    <li>Player12
        <span>1 man of the match</span>
    </li>    
    <p class="results">Goals</p>
    <li>Player1 
        <span>2 goal(s)</span>
    </li>
    <p class="results">Assists</p>
    <p class="results">Yellow Cards</p>
    <li>Player2                                             
    <span>1 yellow card(s)</span>
    </li>
    <p class="results">Red Cards</p>
</ul>
```

As you can see, the p and li elements are not "mapped" to each other. They are kind of independent, even though p is the heading and li the content. It's easy to scrape the Man of the Match, because the element to scrape will be always "ul/li[1]/span/text()" and there is just one man of the match. But now occurs the problem. Since goals, assists etc. don't have an own class and are not listed under "p", it can happen that there will be more players who scored, received cards etc. So in one example li[3] is a player who scored a goal. In another example (when there are no goals), li[3] could be a yellow card.

Let's see another example:

```
<ul class="stats">
    <p class="results">Man of The Match</p>
    <li>Player12
        <span>1 man of the match</span>
    </li>    
    <p class="results">Goals</p>
    <li>Player1 
    <span>2 goal(s)</span>
    </li>
    <li>Player2 
    <span>3 goal(s)</span>
    </li>
    <p class="results">Assists</p>
    <p class="results">Yellow Cards</p>
    <li>Player2                                             
    <span>1 yellow card(s)</span>
    </li>
    <li>Player13 
    <span>3 goal(s)</span>
    </li>  
    <p class="results">Red Cards</p>
</ul>
```

So in the example above, we will have a different xpath for all the li-elements.

How do I write my code in order to tell scrapy which "li"-element belongs to Goals, Assists, Yellow Cards etc., since the structure of the website is not really clear?

I tried:

```
'player_stats' = extract_with_xpath('ul[@class="stats"]/p/li/text()')
```

which gives me all the li elements but not the spans. Of course I could add span in the end but than I won't be able to map it to the write item (because li's are always changing). But actually I would like to have the items goals, assists, yellow cards etc.

Basically I want to know how to map elements to the same items, that will change their xpath depending on the number of elements added (in this case goals, assists etc.). I hope I could make my problem clear, since English isn't my first language, I apologize for a possible bad description. Thanks in advance, help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Basically I want to get all li elements until another p element appears (since p[1], p[2] etc. will always be the same, because that are the constant headings). Can I do this with "following-siblings" and/or "preceding-siblings"?

Answer (score 0):

This line: `response.css("ul.stats p, ul.stats li")`
 
 returns a list of `p` and `ul` tag selectors in the same order as in response.
After that you need to separately process each type of nodes.

```
player_data = {}
categoty = ""
for node in response.css("ul.stats p, ul.stats li"):  #returs list of p and li tags selectors in the same order as in response
    if '<p class="results"' in node.extract():
        category = node.css("::text").extract_first()
    if '<li>' in node.extract():
        player = node.css("::text").extract_first().strip()
        if player not in player_data.keys():
            player_data[player]={}
        player_data[player][category]=node.css("span::text").extract_first().strip()


print(player_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [XPath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp)’s `preceding-sibling` to find the `li` elements that are preceded by a specific key:

```
stats = response.css('.stats')
for key in stats.css('p::text').getall():
    for li in stats.xpath('./li[./preceding-sibling::p[1][contains(text(), "{}")]]'.format(key)):
        player = li.xpath('./text()').get()
        value = li.css('span::text').get()
```